# Download a byte array in binary format

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary

I'm working on this code where I want to download a byte array, and its working at this point, but the downloaded file is encoded in ascii.

The downloaded file shows
"65,66,67,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

but I was expecting "ABC"

How can I change this code to get this file in binary format?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Writing a binary file</h1>

<script>
    
  var dados = new Int8Array(10);

  dados[0]=65;
  dados[1]=66;
  dados[2]=67;
  
  function download()
  {
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,' + dados );
    element.setAttribute('download', "teste.bin" );
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
  download();


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the downloaded file is encoded in ascii."  Q: What exactly does that mean?  Do you get a file ("teste.bin")?  Is it 3 bytes, (65, 66, 67)?  Which happen to map to the ASCII letters "A", "B" and "C"?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Have you considered using `fetch()`? It will save data to a file, in any format you specify. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: these values are just an example. This code is intended to be part of a custom video aplication where the user will edit video and generate this .bin file and download it. I alredy have this video app kind of working, but the downloaded file is in ascii, so an array byte takes up to 3 bytes on downloaded file. I want to put every array byte in just 1 byte. I'm a firmware developer used to C, these WEB languages are new for me. I will look at fetch().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - Now I see what's happening.

Thank you for updating your post :)

You're inadvertantly converting Int8Array "dados" into a text string.  Whoops!

Here's an alternative approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Writing a binary file</h1>

<script>  
  function download(bytes, fname)  {
    debugger;
    let blob = new Blob([bytes], {type:"application/octet-stream"});
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = fname;
    link.click();
  }

  let dados = new Int8Array(10);
  dados[0]=65;
  dados[1]=66;
  dados[2]=67;

  download(dados, "teste.bin"); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would also consider terrymorse's excellent suggestion about using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

'Hope that helps!